# Testcafe fails with ECONNREFUSED in GitLab CI running in a Ubuntu-Container

Tags: testing, gitlab, automated-tests, chromium, testcafe

For a project, I using the glubuntu-php docker image from https://git.var-lab.com/dev-tools/glubuntu-php. There are some packages pre-installed, including the `chromium-browser` package.

In the pipeline, I want to run testcafe for end-to-end-testing using the pre-installed chromium-browser in headles mode:

```json
variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  JOB_IMAGE: git.var-lab.com:5050/dev-tools/glubuntu-php:latest-php-8.1
  GIT_STRATEGY: clone

e2e_tests:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'
    - if: ($CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH)
  image: $JOB_IMAGE
  variables:
    BACKEND_SERVICE_URL: http://localhost
    PUBLIC_BACKEND_SERVICE_URL: http://localhost
  before_script:
    - apt update
    - apt install -y x11-apps
  script:
    - mysql -h database -u root -proot <<< "SET GLOBAL sql_mode = '';"
    - mysql -h database -u root -proot symfony < data/sql_dump.sql
    - git clone https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@git.xxx.de/xxx/xxx-software.git
    - cd xxx-software
    - composer install
    - php -d variables_order=EGPCS -S $BACKEND_SERVICE_URL public/index.php &
    - cd ../
    - git clone https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@git.xxx.de/xxx/xxx-frontend.git
    - cd xxx-frontend
    - npm install
    - npm run dev &
    - cd ../
    - npm install
    - chromium --headless --no-sandbox --remote-debugging-port=34135 http://localhost:3000 &
    - ps aux
    - npm run test-ci -- -b
    - npm run test-ci -- --debug-on-fail
```

Testcafe-configuration:

```json
{
  "disableScreenshots": false,
  "screenshots": {
    "path": "./screenshots/",
    "takeOnFails": true
  },
  "qrCode": true,
  "color": true
}
```

packages.json:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "testcafe chrome",
    "test-ci": "testcafe 'chromium --headless --no-sandbox'"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "testcafe": "^2.2.0"
  }
}
```

The pipeline fails with

```
$ npm run test-ci -- --debug-on-fail
> test-ci
> testcafe 'chromium --headless --no-sandbox' --debug-on-fail
ERROR Unable to open the "chromium: --headless --no-sandbox" browser due to the following error:
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:40635
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1487:16)
    at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17)
Type "testcafe -h" for help.
```

Locally, the e2e-tests succeeds when I use the command `npm run test`.

Comment: At first glance, I see two issues in the information you shared:

1) The 'headless' option is incorrectly set up. The correct way is the following: "testcafe 'chromium:headless --no-sandbox'".
2) The 'debug-on-fail' option is interactive. You should not use it on the CI.